# MySQL Database import causing issue special characters (ě ř č ů)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, iso-8859-1

Hi I recently changed the hosting provider for my website. When doing this I exported the mysql database I had in my previous cpanel phpmyadmin. It had CHARACTER SET latin1 and COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci. After I importing it to my new phpmyadmin I saw there was an issue with displaying the characters written in Czech ě ř č ů which appeared as question mark or  weird symbols etc. I also wasn't able to insert these letters at first but after changing the table CHARSET to utf8 I'm able to insert them. But how do I export the data from my old database and import it in the new one without messing up the data? Here's what the database looks like:

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";
    
    
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
    
    --
    -- Database: `sambajiu_samba`
    --
    
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    
    CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `fname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `surname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `telephone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `age_group` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `hear` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `experience` text,
      `subscriber` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      `booking_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `lesson_time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `booked_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ALTER TABLE `bookings` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

    ALTER TABLE `bookings` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=345;
```

Comment: *I exported the mysql database* How did you do this exactly? and how do you import?

Comment: I did it with the export button in my cpanel phpmyadmin. I did the same to import it to my new host

Answer (score 0):

Czech is not handled by `latin1`.  It would be better to use `utf8mb4` (which can handle virtually everything in the world).  Outside of MySQL, it is called "UTF-8".

How did you do the "export" and "import"?  What is in the file?  Can you get the hex of a small portion of the exported file -- we need to check what encoding was used for the Czech characters.

As for "as question mark or weird symbols", see question marks and Mojibake in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

Your hex probably intended to say

```
Rezervovat trénink zda
```

In the middle of the hex is

```
C383 C2A9
```

Which is UTF-8 for `Ã©`.  When you display the data, you might see that, or you might see the desired `é`.  In the latter case, the browser is *probably* "helping" you by decoding the data twice.  For further discussion on this, see "double encoding" in the link above.

"Fixing the data" is quite messy:

```
 CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(
 UNHEX('52657A6572766F766174207472C383C2A96E696E6B207A6461') 
   USING utf8mb4) USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)

==> 'Rezervovat trénink zda'
```

But, I don't think we are finished.  that acute-e is a valid character in latin1.  You mentioned 4 Czech accented letters that, I think, are not in Latin1.  Latin5 and dec8 *may* be relevant.

Comment: I did it using phpmyadmin. I've added a sample of the database to my question

Comment: @admec986 - Was `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` on the table both before and after?  Were there any parameters on the dump and load?  What was/is the default charset for the connection to the database before/after?

Comment: No when I imported it it was CHARSET=latin1 but since this didn't allow be to write the special characters in the form I changed it to utf8. However this didn't solve the problem of all the original data being completely messed up. Both of the phpmyadmin I imported it from and exported to has the Server connection collation :  utf8mb4_unicode_ci . I don't think there was any parameters I just clicked export or the import button

Comment: With `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` for a small amount of data, I can help you determine how much damage there is.  `HEX()` shows what is actually on the disk; all the "charset" clues are less definitive.

Comment: Ok so I ran this for a table named home_section_five: SELECT s5_btn1, HEX(s5_btn1) FROM home_section_five WHERE id=1;;; and it returns 52657A6572766F766174207472C383C2A96E696E6B207A6461...